# v4l2 commands with no I2C

Tags: c, linux, v4l2

Does v4l2 need I2C commands to gather data from a camera module?

We are working with a camera of which the data is transformed to MIPI in a bridge. This means that we have no I2C capabilities with this camera. However, we are trying to write a driver for it (based on [this example](https://gist.github.com/maxlapshin/1253534)), and I was trying to get some information using v4l2 commands in the terminal. An example:

```
v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --all
```

Gives the response:

```
    Driver Info:
        Driver name      : mx6s-csi
        Card type        : i.MX6S_CSI
        Bus info         : platform:30a90000.csi1_bridge
        Driver version   : 4.14.98
        Capabilities     : 0x84200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Priority: 0
Video input : 0 (Camera: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 0/0
        Pixel Format      : ''
        Field             : Any
        Bytes per Line    : 0
        Size Image        : 0
        Colorspace        : Default
        Transfer Function : Default (maps to Rec. 709)
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 0, Height 0
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 0, Height 0
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Crop: Left 0, Top 0, Width 0, Height 0
```

As you can see, everything is 0. However, I am sure (checked with an oscilloscope) that there is data coming out of the bridge as well as a clock. I think that the v4l2 commands need I2C to gather data, but I am not sure.

PS: if anyone knows any examples of drivers without I2C please let me know!

Comment: I know jack about V4L, but I'd be amazed anything used a slow bus like I2C for pulling data out of a camera. Also, surely the whole thing about V4L is it that it's an API so you're not worrying about hardware layers? Are you trying to write a really low level driver?

Comment: @DiBosco v4l2 uses I2C to get information data out of the camera (handshakes, reading information registers,  etc.). V4L is indeed an API which can be used as a driver. The basic thing I am trying to do is make use of this API to get the data out off the camera without it ever needing the I2C. Which proves much harder than it seems.

Comment: The v4l2 core itself does not depend on I2C. Some devices use I2C for configuration and control. If your camera module has I2C, it probably needs it for something. For examples of drivers that do not depend on I2C, look in the "Kconfig" files under the drivers/media directory for configuration options that neither `depends on` nor `select` `I2C`.

Comment: @IanAbbott My camera does not need I2C at all, so any driver in which we can set up some information (e.g. pixel width) and does not use I2C is very much welcomed!
where are those files you point out? On the mendel Linux system there are a "platform" and a "usb" folder in that directory (/lib/modules/4.14.98-imx/kernel/drivers/media/) , neither of which seem to have a connection to v4l on first sight? I cannot find any online examples either though.

Comment: For example (all under "drivers/media/platform/"): "ti-vpe/cal.c", "ti-vpe/vpe.c", "stm32/stm32-dcmi.c".

Comment: @IanAbbott Tank You!! Under the same folder for me are just some .ko files and nothing more. Luckily the examples you gave are all online. I have been able to find the Git repo where they stand. Thanks again.